# Headers required for ZAPI API Calls

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I am new to Zapi(Zephyr API).

**Question 1:** I am one of Jira user in my project. Jira admin has installed ZAPI(trial version).

Now as a regular user will i able to access ZAPI API's with user ID and credentials

**Question 2:** 
I am trying to evaluate GET call

Endpoint : https://zephyr-cloud/rest/zapi/latest/systemInfo

Headers i am using in postman

```
Authorization": " Basic " + b64encode(username + ":" + password)
Content-Type:application/json
```

Please let me know, what I am missing here or else is there any other way I can get access to fetch details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse session random value from key "AO-7DEABF" (or similar)

from HTML page after authorization into Jira

add then add this (key: value) to each ZAPI request during the session as header

Answer (score -1):

What error are you getting?
Only Authorization and content-type is required for making request via postman. You can encode the username/password from https://www.base64decode.org/ and directly put the encoded value (it will start with the word "basic").